# Como remover parte de uma string até um ponto determinado

Tags: javascript

Bom dia a todos. Estou começando com Javascript e estou com dificuldades para remover uma parte de uma string até um ponto determinado.

tenho a string:

**"21/07/2020 16:34:42 - Adriana Gomes Carneiro (Comments) TESTE DANIEL"** OU **"21/07/2020 16:34:42 - Daniel Silva (Comments) COMMENT REJECTED"**
O nome depois da data sempre mudará.

Gostaria de remover parte da string até **"(Comments)..."**, mantendo por exemplo: **"(Comments) COMMENT REJECTED"**.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta.
Poste o que você encontrou até agora, poste seu código completo para que possa ser ajudado e irá ajudar outros no futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizar o [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) em conjunto com o método [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), para extrair as strings necessárias.
Segue um exemplo:

```
const linha = "21/07/2020 16:34:42 - Adriana Gomes Carneiro (Comments) TESTE DANIEL";
const idx = linha.indexOf(" (Comments) ");
const primeiraParteStr = linha.substring(0,idx);
// "21/07/2020 16:34:42 - Adriana Gomes Carneiro"
const segundaParteStr = linha.substring(idx, linha.length);
// " (Comments) TESTE DANIEL"
```

Observe que na variável `segundaParteStr`, temos um espaço no começo da string (talvez indesejado), para remover é só utilizar o método [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

```
segundaParteStr = linha.substring(44,linha.length).trim()
```

Comment: Obrigado. Ajudou bastante. 

Abraços